# iOS to tvOS communication is not working

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming, tvos

I am trying to make an iPad and an Apple TV communicate between each other with this project I found on github: https://github.com/arn00s/iOS-tvOS

The quick demo perfectly works on simulators but I cannot make it work on a real iPad and a real Apple TV (neither with an iPhone). All my devices are on the last version. I do not have any error message. There is just nothing happening. But I do know I press the button and I also know that the text is sent. But somehow the Apple TV does not receive the text.

Comment: Have you switched bluetooth on your iPad/iPhone? Does the AppleTV respond to a remote? Is it paired with a remote? If so reset it factory defaults

Comment: The AppleTV respond correctly to its remote. Bluetooth was off on my iPad/iPhone. The connection is suppose to be handled by wifi. You propose to reset entirely the Apple TV?

Comment: Your right; I didn't look at the code. Bluetooth isn't in the picture [I just looked]. But wait your trying to make your iPad and AppleTV talk across a network? Are they in the same subnet? How is the AppleTv getting its IP address, how is your iPad/iPhone getting IP-Address?

Comment: They are getting the IP address by DHCP. Yes they are both with the same subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 and with respective IP addresses 10.0.1.40 and 10.0.1.34. They have both the same router and DNS address as well (10.0.1.1). And they are on the same wifi of course :)

Comment: Did you turn on bluetooth anyway; I didn't notice the code; but may it is in there. If you want to setup a local streaming connection between a ATV and an iPad; you would normally need to be running bluetooth on both devices, since they use bluetooth for the initial handshake.

Comment: I just tried a few time with bluetooth on. No difference. I noticed that on simulators, they have the same IP address, while on real device they have different IP address. I tried to manually put the same IP address. Not working either.

Comment: Magohamoth, they should never have the same IP address if the plan is for them to communicate across the wire. I got an ATV talking to a iPad no problem, but using bluetooth central/peripheral model. Try this tutorial perhaps. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-theoretical-overview--mobile-20728

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these two items in both your `Info.plist` files:

> Apps that use the local network must provide a usage string in their
> Info.plist with the key NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription. Apps that use
> Bonjour must also declare the services they browse, using the
> NSBonjourServices key.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>comm</string>
</plist>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>_ClientServer._tcp</string>
</array>
</plist>
```